# How to divide the two connected words?

Tags: regex

Like This:

ILove => I Love

only need to add a space between two words.

Comment: @gion_12 ,I update my question, Please unclose my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both words are capitalized,

```
import re
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'ILove') # => 'I Love'
```

This basically inserts a space before any capital letter, provided the capital letter is preceded by a letter.

Comment: thank you for your clear and concise answer!